# Regex replace with occurrences count

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

I must do a regex search and replace (for example in sublime text 2) to obtain the following result.

From:

```
aab1
aaba2
aabb3
baba4
bbba5
```

To:

```
ccc1
cccc2
cccc3
cccc4
cccc5
```

I'm using these patterns but the result is that aab become only c.

```
\n(a|b)+([0-9])
\nc\2
```

result:

```
c1
c2
c3
c4
c5
```

Note: the \n is essential because i'm tryng to replace only the pattern that is at the start of the line. Whithout that my regex works.

Comment: What's the significance of the newline and `[0-9]` in the pattern ? As your question is posted now, @Kasramvd answered it.

Comment: Of course, the expected result from the regexp you use is the one you put on the output.  By the way, `\n` applies for a end of line character.  Perhaps you are missing something.

Comment: I updated the question: the \n is essential because i'm tryng to replace only the pattern that is at the start of the line. Whithout that my regex works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[ab](?=\D*\d+)
```

You can use this and replace by `c`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sS2dM8/30

Comment: If you are going to lookahead for the trailing digits, his regex also validates a leading newline at the beginning.

Comment: @user2342558 it cannot be...the site recognises any PCRE compatible regexes

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the result of following regex:

```
/[ab]/g
```

with :

```
/c/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do this with the JavaScript string `replace` function:

```js
let str = `aab1
aaba2
aabb3
baba4
bbba5`;

str = str.replace(/(\n|^)([a-z]+)([0-9]+)/g, (m, m1, m2, m3) => m1+"c".repeat(m2.length)+m3);
```

You can learn more about the use of a function as the second parameter in the `replace` function on the [MDN regex replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) page.